# I need high performance data redundancy over IP

Tags: database, networking, backup, redundancy

I have a database that I need to provide redundancy for.

It is Codebase, but using a typical SQL database uses too much CPU, and having the DB offsite causes too much latency in my process.

I need a viable solution for providing data redundancy with an offsite location for my time criticla process.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a stupid answer, but have you thought about a mirror?

Answer (score 1):

If you have a mostly read scenario you should look into memcached, it might solve part of your problem.